# Making a searchbox to filter text and its entities

Tags: jquery

I have a list of checkbox options, below is the code snippet from my Laravel blade.

```
<!--start of major list-->
                      <div class="tag-majors" >
                        <p class="font-weight-bold text-xs-center">
                          Major:
                        </p>
                        <div class="" style="max-height:300px;overflow:hidden;overflow-y:auto;">
                        <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search.."> <!--filter search box-->
                        <div id="testmajor"> <!--div for filter results-->
                          <div class="m-a-05">
                            <label class="c-input c-checkbox">
                              <input type="checkbox" class="majors-all">
                              <span class="c-indicator"></span>
                              All
                            </label>
                          </div>
                          @foreach ($majors as $key => $major)
                            <div class="m-a-05">
                              <label class="c-input c-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="majors[]" value="{{ $major->id }}">
                                <span class="c-indicator"></span>
                                {{ $major->name }}
                              </label>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                        </div>
                      </div>
 <!--end of major list-->
```

My goal is to make a search filter to search for the majors instead of having to search all the way through. Currently, I have this.

[image]

I  managed to get the search box working but when I search for something, I only get the text to be returned and the checkbox goes missing.

[image]

This is my search function:

```
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
              var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
              $("#testmajor *").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
              });
            });
          });
```

I've been looking around StackOverflow and other sources trying to figure out a way to include the checkbox together and I still am trying. I''m hoping to get some input as to how I could tackle this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this:

1. Instead of toggling you can use $('#selector').append().html(
   // checkbox HTML and data code here
   ) 
   So your filtered data will get appended. But you need to clear before you start a new search. Sound tricky but might work.
2. You can add a key specific class to topmost div of `$majors`. Then on .filter() function can hide rest of `checkbox` divs and show as per filtered keys.

Comment: What you mean by key specific class is to wrap my 'm-a-05' in another class and filter all the elements with that?

Comment: Yes. That class will be unique for each div 'm-a-05'... Something like <div class=`m-a-05 major${key}`>

Answer (score 0):

After hours on working on this I finally figured it out. The solution turned out to be quite a simple one. To anyone having the same issue, here's my solution.

HTML:

```
<!--start of major list-->
                      <div class="tag-majors" >
                        <p class="font-weight-bold text-xs-center">
                          Major:
                        </p>
                        <div class="" style="max-height:300px;overflow:hidden;overflow-y:auto;">
                        <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search.."> <!--filter search box-->
                        <div class="testmajor"> <!--div for filter results-->
                          <div class="m-a-05">
                            <label class="c-input c-checkbox">
                              <input type="checkbox" class="majors-all">
                              <span class="c-indicator"></span>
                              All
                            </label>
                          </div>
                          @foreach ($majors as $key => $major)
                            <div class="m-a-05">
                              <label class="c-input c-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="majors[]" value="{{ $major->id }}">
                                <span class="c-indicator"></span>
                                {{ $major->name }}
                              </label>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                        </div>
                      </div>
 <!--end of major list-->
```

JQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#myInput').keyup(function(){

           // Search text
           var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

           // Hide all content class element
          $('.testmajor .m-a-05').hide();

         // Search 
         $('.testmajor .c-input').each(function(){

        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(""+text+"") != -1 ){
        $(this).closest('.m-a-05').show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```